# Firebase Crashlytics に dSYM ファイルが一部自動アップロードされない

Tags: swift, ios, firebase

### 背景

Xcodeプロジェクトに、CocoaPodsでFirebase Crashlyticsを導入しております。
その際、dSYMファイル（解析ファイル）は自動アップロードができるように設定したいと思っております。

アプリは以下のように複数のXcodeプロジェクトからできており、メインプロジェクトからAプロジェクトやBプロジェクトを使用している箇所があります。

```
- Aプロジェクト
- Bプロジェクト
- メインプロジェクト
```

---

### 困っていること

Firebaseの公式サイトを参考に、メインプロジェクトの Build Phases > New Run Script Phases を以下のように設定しました。

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started?hl=ja&platform=ios
https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=ios&hl=ja

shell

```
"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"
```

Input Files

```
${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}
${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Resources/DWARF/${PRODUCT_NAME}
${DWARF_DSYM_FOLDER_PATH}/${DWARF_DSYM_FILE_NAME}/Contents/Info.plist
$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(UNLOCALIZED_RESOURCES_FOLDER_PATH)/GoogleService-Info.plist
$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(EXECUTABLE_PATH)
```

しかし、Firebase Consoleを見ると、「見つからない（オプション）」と表示されてしまいます。
※一部はアップロードできているのですが、一部はアップロードできていない状況です。（以下のようなイメージです）

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

この「見つからない（オプション）」も、「アップロード済み」にするためには、どのように設定すれば良いでしょうか。
初歩的な質問で恐れ入りますが、もし分かる方がいましたら、ご教示いただけますと幸いです。